# Wordpress 3.2.1. wrong umlauts in search results?

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

I installed a brand new wordpress blog and when I search for posts, the umlauts are displayed the wrong way in the search results:

I get **Lange bevor es in Amerika die ersten BlockhÃ¤user gab** but what I expect is **Lange bevor es in Amerika die ersten Blockhäuser gab**.

The "ä" becomes "Ã¤" for some reason. On the site itself and in the source code it looks ok, its a "ä". The db charset is utf 8. Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Seeing as this is a vanilla installation and not something you programmed, it's not really on-topic on Stack Overflow. The WordPress support forums would be the better place to ask this. Weird though, this shouldn't happen in a fresh copy out of the box. Can you verify that the page's character set is the same on the content pages and on the search page?

Comment: are you using JS in the process ? is your DB utf-8 ?

Comment: How do I check if my DB is utf8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that proper Content-Type header is not sent or is sent with the wrong encoding. If it's not sent at at all, you can use .htaccess or apache config:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

You should check what is in the Content-Type header by using Google Chrome Developer Tools Network tab when visiting the page or similar tool.